# Showing vertical ScrollBar in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display the vertical ScrollBar always in the DataGridView, But the .Net by default displays the scrollbar when it is needed.

As the picture shows, there's no ScrollBar:

[image: Pic]

Comment: The `DataGridView` control provides no API for that. The `ScrollBars` property can be used to prevent scrollbars appearing when they could be used but can't force scrollbars to be displayed when they can't be of use. Given that they can't be of use in that scenario, may I ask why you want them visible? It may be possible to accomplish in some more complex way but there's nothing straightforward.

Comment: You could derive a custom control from DataGridView and override this behaviour, which also implies, IIRC, providing the scrolling functionality. But, is it worth it, in this case? It looks like a "docking" matter.